# Trapdoor implementation

Tags: hash, algorithm-design, implementation, trapdoor

Please refer to [this](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~eujin/papers/secureindex/secureindex.pdf) secure index paper. On page#6, a `trapdoor` is defined as

```
Trapdoor(Kpriv, w): Given the master key  Kpriv = (k1, … , kr) and word w,
output the trapdoor for word w as:     Tw = (f(w, k1), … , f(w, kr))
```

Can someone please explain it to me using an example?

Let's say we've a word **hello** for which we want to generate a trap door. So, do I first encrypt it with `k1` and then take its hash. And do the same with key k2, k3 etc. Once we have all the hashes, simple concatenate them. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

From the paper, $f$ is a pseudo-random function that produces a result of $s$ bits.

You can think of the master key as a vector of $r$ values each $s$ bits long and for pedagogical purposes I'm sure the trapdoor for $w$ could be thought of as the result of hashing the concatenation of each key value $k$ with the word $w$.